# UWP Scroll Text from end to start

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am implementing a scrolling text that when pointer enters it, it starts scrolling its content.

I am able to get it scrolling using the code below:

```
private DispatcherTimer ScrollingTextTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16) };
ScrollingTextTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    MainTitleScrollViewer.ChangeView(MainTitleScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + 3, null, null);
    if (MainTitleScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset == MainTitleScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth)
    {
        MainTitleScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, null, null);
        ScrollingTextTimer.Stop();
    }
};
```

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="MainTitleScrollViewer"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10,5"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="MainTitleTextBlock"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        FontSize="24"
        Foreground="White" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, there is an additional feature that I want to implement. When the text scrolls to its end, I don't want it to scroll back to the start. I want it to keep scrolling to the start. You can see what I mean from the screenshots I posted below. The screenshots are from Groove Music. You may need to check it out if I didn't explain my question well.

[image: Normal]

[image: Scroll To the End]

A possible solution might be doubling the text and putting some space between them. But I don't know when to stop scrolling if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my way of doing it and source code is [here(xaml)](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/ScrollingTextBlock.xaml) and [here(csharp)](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/ScrollingTextBlock.xaml):

I created a `UserControl` called `ScrollingTextBlock`.

This is XAML content of the `UserControl`.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="TextScrollViewer">
        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalTextBlock" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="RealScrollViewer">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ScrollTextBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Basically, you need two `ScrollViewer`s that overlaps.

The first `ScrollViewer` is for detecting if the text is scrollable.  And the `TextBlock` in it is for putting the text.

The second `ScrollViewer` is the real `ScrollViewer`. You will be scrolling this one not the first one. And the `TextBlock` in it will have its `Text` equal to

```
ScrollTextBlock.Text = NormalTextBlock.Text + new string(' ', 10) + NormalTextBlock.Text
```

The `new string(' ', 10)` is just some blank space to make your text not look concatenated tightly, which you can see from the image in the question. You can change it into whatever you want.

Then in the csharp code you need (explanations are in the comments):

```
    // Using 16ms because 60Hz is already good for human eyes.
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16) };

    public ScrollingTextBlock()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Calculate the total offset to scroll. It is fixed after your text is set.
            // Since we need to scroll to the "start" of the text,
            // the offset is equal the length of your text plus the length of the space,
            // which is the difference of the ActualWidth of the two TextBlocks.
            double offset = ScrollTextBlock.ActualWidth - NormalTextBlock.ActualWidth;
            // Scroll it horizontally.
            // Notice the Math.Min here. You cannot scroll more than offset.
            // " + 2" is just the distance it advances,
            // meaning that it also controls the speed of the animation.
            RealScrollViewer.ChangeView(Math.Min(RealScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + 2, offset), null, null);
            // If scroll to the offset
            if (RealScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset == offset)
            {
                // Re-display the NormalTextBlock first so that the text won't blink because they overlap.
                NormalTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                // Hide the ScrollTextBlock.
                // Hiding it will also set the HorizontalOffset of RealScrollViewer to 0,
                // so that RealScrollViewer will be scrolling from the beginning of ScrollTextBlock next time.
                ScrollTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                // Stop the animation/ticking.
                timer.Stop();
            }
        };
    }

    public void StartScrolling()
    {
        // Checking timer.IsEnabled is to avoid restarting the animation when the text is already scrolling.
        // IsEnabled is true if timer has started, false if timer is stopped.
        // Checking TextScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth is for making sure the text is scrollable.
        if (timer.IsEnabled || TextScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth == 0) return;
        // Display this first so that user won't feel NormalTextBlock will be hidden.
        ScrollTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        // Hide the NormalTextBlock so that it won't overlap with ScrollTextBlock when scrolling.
        NormalTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        // Start the animation/ticking.
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect of this kind of marquee is recommended to use `Storyboard`. The timer may cause lack due to time interval.

Here is a complete demo, I hope to help you.

**xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ScrollViewer Width="200" 
                          PointerEntered="ScrollViewer_PointerEntered" 
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                          PointerExited="ScrollViewer_PointerExited">
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" x:Name="TitleBlock">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0"/>
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>

            <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Gotye" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
Storyboard _scrollAnimation;
public ScrollTextPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    string text = "How about you?";
    TitleBlock.Text = text + "    " + text;
}

private void ScrollViewer_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AnimationInit();
    _scrollAnimation.Begin();
}

private void ScrollViewer_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _scrollAnimation.Stop();
}
public void AnimationInit()
{
    _scrollAnimation = new Storyboard();
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    animation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
    animation.From = 0;
    // Here you need to calculate based on the number of spaces and the current FontSize
    animation.To = -((TitleBlock.ActualWidth/2)+13);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, TitleBlock);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)");
    _scrollAnimation.Children.Add(animation);
}
```

Simply put, scrolling the TextBlock horizontally is more controllable than scrolling the ScrollViewer.

The idea is similar to yours, using a string stitching method to achieve seamless scrolling, and calculate the width of the space by the current font size, so as to accurately scroll to the beginning of the second string.

Best regards.

Comment: How do you calculate the width of space according to the font size?

Comment: This depends on the font. If it is a monospaced font, then the space is 1/2 font size. If it is not, then it needs to be tested. There is no suitable algorithm to determine it. You need to adjust it yourself.

Comment: How do you know if animation has finished playing? The expected effect is that, when pointer enters, the animation begins. It will keep playing the animation until the text has finished scrolling regardless of pointer exit event and pointer re-enter event.

Comment: And I don't think there will be a lack because my `Interval` is 16ms which is about 60Hz. That's good for human eyes. Animation Duration is not good for me because if the text is very long then the scrolling will be very fast.

Comment: Notice the `From` and `To` properties of `animation`, which mark the start and end points. At the same time, you can also listen to the `_scrollAnimation.Completed` event, which is why I use the Storyboard.

Comment: Animations can often be adjusted. You can determine the playback time of the animation based on the actual width of the TextBlock, such as `animation.Duration = TitleBlock.ActualWidth/TitleBlock.FontSize`